# Retornar na view mais de uma lista de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

No meu return View(), tem como eu retornar duas ou mais listas? Essas listas são resultados de uma consulta linq.

Comment: Sim @pnet. Podes retornar como ViewBag ou como ViewData, depois é só percorrer na view ;)

Comment: Há diferenças entre eles, tipo performance, "mais fácil de trabalhar", mais elegante, enfim, há diferença? Quando usar um ou outro?

Comment: Ambas são acessíveis para trabalhar, agora em performance não te sei dizer qual a melhor. Mas acredito que não exista muita diferença

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode colocar no ViewBag

```
ViewBag.Lista1 = new List<>();
ViewBag.Lista2 = new List<>();

return View();
```

Ai a View voce acessa da mesma forma:

```
@ViewBag.Lista1
```

Agora voce pode se quiser, criar uma classe c# ViewModel que é faz "wrapper" juntando as duas lista numa nova classe

```
return View(new MyViewModel{ Lista1 = new List<>(), Lista2 = new List<>() });
```

Ai a View voce acessa:

```
@Model.Lista1
```

Saca ?

Comment: Eu vi esse exemplo net e estou agora vendo como fazer para satisfazer a minha necessidade